# Connect to RTC jazz server using the java and retrieve the work items

Tags: java, api, rtc, workitem, ibm-jazz

Our organization uses an RTC server to maintain all the work items. I need to develop a java client and connect to the jazz server [https://:9443/ccm/] and retrieve the RTC items.

Please let me know if there are any java  api's to connect to the RTC server and retrieve the workitems and also update the workitems

Comment: It looks it's not that easy if even the jazz people recommend: `The easiest way to automate the connection to an RTC server and perform SCM operations (e.g. share, load, check-in) is to use the command-line interface (CLI). The command-line interface can be called from a script or launched using ProcessBuilder in Java.

More information about the CLI can be found in these articles:
https://jazz.net/library/article/620
https://jazz.net/library/article/1031 ` [here](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/91843/how-to-connect-to-rtc-server-using-java-application/92524).

Comment: AFAIK The CLI does not support interacting work items, you have to use the REST API for that.